# Create View in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, view

I came up with a question with views, I know that views result generate when it has requested but if someone use `CREATE VIEW` several times with the same code then what happens? SSMS does the query several times or after the first time it ignores the view code and just continue to the next line?

For example:

```
CREATE VIEW foo
    SELECT ...

    other SQL code

    SELECT ....
```

Again request for construct a same view - for no reason -

```
CREATE VIEW foo
    SELECT ...
```

P.S. I'm new into this topic, just take it easy :)

P.S. sorry for bad English, if you need further details, just ask :)

Comment: CREATE VIEW can only contain a single query. Did you try your first example? It won't work unless you put a GO between the first SELECT and anything after it. In which case only the first SELECT is part of the view. Anything after that just gets executed.

Comment: SQLserver will throw an error if you attempt to create a view which already exists.